# Geonode Layers Page Invalid URL

Tags: python-2.7, web, gis, open-source, osgeo

I have uploaded a layer to geonode using the web interface. I would now like to see   the layers details.

I have debugging turned on. This is the error page.

This feels like something I would need to change in local_settings.py? I have default values except for the following:

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = True

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the geoserver URL which is missing a /

Make sure that your geoserver url is correctly set in settings:

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/local_settings.py.geoserver.sample#L110

and correctly redirected in apache conf:

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-project/blob/master/scripts/misc/apache2/geonode.conf.sample#L105